# Prohibiting copy construction and copy assignment in C++

Tags: c++

To prohibit copy construction and copy assignment, I've seen the [boost noncopyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable) class and in the Google style guide the [DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Copy_Constructors.) macro. Is there any reason to prefer one of the techniques over the other, or any subtle differences one should be aware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer boost noncopyable over the macro because it's not a macro and it is easier (IMO) to use.

In real code, i'm using neither of them and write the two declarations needed myself.

A subtle difference you might be interested in, though, is that using that macro or your own declarations will not give a compiler error when the class itself tries to copy the object (but rather fail to link later on). `noncopyable` however will also signal a compiler error in this case, because it's the base-class that has the functions declared private, not the class itself.

Comment: Another small advantage about using `noncopyable` is that the error message produced by the compiler will include the word "noncopyable", which might make it easier to track down what the error actually is. (I don't know how this compares to the `DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN`-macro, which I have never used)

Answer (score 3):

I always make the copy constructor and assignment operator private, without implementation:

- this prevents someone making copies outside the class (will give compile errors)
- this prevents the class itself also from making copies of itself (will give link errors)

I also add a clear comment (just above the prototypes of the copy constructor and assignment operator) to indicate that I do this to prevent someone making copies (as a reminder to future developers).

In my opinion, this solution is clear, does not rely on external libraries or macro's and is easy to understand.

Comment: It does have the disadvantage that its not easily searched for - both the use of derivation and the use of a macro can easily be found via text searches.

Comment: @Neil the comments provide excellent tools for finding them by using searches (i don't think i ever had the need to look-up all non-copyable classes, though).

Comment: @Johannes Only if they contain standardised text, in which case I have to wonder why bother.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the rule of avoid inheritance wherever possible, I always use a macro - in this case my own. Of course, there is the other rule, about avoiding macros...

Comment: I really see no harm in privately inheriting from `boost::noncopyable`...? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

I would never use the `DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN` macro because you have to put it in the `private` part of the class declaration. What if you (*or someone maintaining your code*) by mistake put it in the `public` part? The problem is that it is not obvious at all that "`DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN`" should be put in the private part: the name of the macro seems to imply that it will disallow copy and assignment independently of where you have declared it.

The `noncopyable` base class avoids this issue entirely.

However, the fastest, most readable, and portable way is to explicitly declare the constructors in the private part of the class.

Comment: What do you mean by "fastest"? What is particularly slow about using for example `boost::noncopyable`? And what is nonportable about either of the proposed solutions?

Comment: I mean fastest for you to implement... Non portable means that you rely in both case on non standard code.

Comment: In that case, I respectfully disagree. I think `boost::noncopyable` is faster to write, and it requires less thinking. It is also portable, and does not rely on non-standard code. (But you do of course need the `noncopyable.hpp`-file) (I understand "non-standard code" as code that violates the C++ standard)

Comment: Of course "non standard code" is the short version for "code that is not in the standard library" (I never worked on a real-life project that used boost). This also means faster since you don't have to handle a dependency.
Requiring less thinking isn't usually a good thing. And this is not even thinking, is just declaring two constructors.

Answer (score 0):

The two techniques are [practically] the same. One uses a macro to save typing (you still have to place it where you would normally place the code) and the other provides the facility through a base class that you extend.

Avoiding macros is a good thing but extending a class just to avoid placing the copy constructor in the private section of your class seems confusing as a reader.

Any reason you dont just do what these two methods do within your class?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code (heavily inspired by [noncopyable_test.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/utility/noncopyable_test.cpp) on boost's website):

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(TypeName) \
  TypeName(const TypeName&);   \
  void operator=(const TypeName&)

class BoostNoCopy : boost::noncopyable {
 public:
  BoostNoCopy() { cout << "BoostNoCopy failed." << endl; }
};

class MacroNoCopy {
 public:
  MacroNoCopy() { cout << "MacroNoCopy failed." << endl; }
 private:
  DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(MacroNoCopy);
};

class ExplicitNoCopy {
 public:
  ExplicitNoCopy() { cout << "ExplicitNoCopy failed." << endl; }
 private:
  ExplicitNoCopy(const ExplicitNoCopy&);
  void operator=(const ExplicitNoCopy&);
};

int main() {
  typedef BoostNoCopy NotCopyable;

  NotCopyable a;
  NotCopyable b(a);
  a = b;

  return 0;
}
```

By setting the typedef in main() to `BoostNoCopy`, `MacroNoCopy`, or `ExplicitNoCopy`, you get the following compiler errors (using i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2):

### boost::noncopyable

```
/usr/local/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp: In copy constructor ‘BoostNoCopy::BoostNoCopy(const BoostNoCopy&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp:27: error: ‘boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable(const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable&)’ is private
main.cpp:9: error: within this context
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:33: note: synthesized method ‘BoostNoCopy::BoostNoCopy(const BoostNoCopy&)’ first required here 
/usr/local/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp: In member function ‘BoostNoCopy& BoostNoCopy::operator=(const BoostNoCopy&)’:
/usr/local/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp:28: error: ‘const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable& boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::operator=(const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable&)’ is private
main.cpp:9: error: within this context
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:34: note: synthesized method ‘BoostNoCopy& BoostNoCopy::operator=(const BoostNoCopy&)’ first required here
```

### Macro

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:18: error: ‘MacroNoCopy::MacroNoCopy(const MacroNoCopy&)’ is private
main.cpp:33: error: within this context
main.cpp:18: error: ‘void MacroNoCopy::operator=(const MacroNoCopy&)’ is private
main.cpp:34: error: within this context
```

### Explicit

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:25: error: ‘ExplicitNoCopy::ExplicitNoCopy(const ExplicitNoCopy&)’ is private
main.cpp:33: error: within this context
main.cpp:26: error: ‘void ExplicitNoCopy::operator=(const ExplicitNoCopy&)’ is private
main.cpp:34: error: within this context
```

Even if you can parse through the compiler error given when using boost::noncopyable, it definitely takes much longer to do so. For the macro and explicit cases, the error is pretty obvious.

So, it seems that the tradeoff is that the boost::noncopyable use requires knowledge of what it means, how it's used, and how to parse the compiler errors; but, it's much more succinct in the code. The macro (Google/Qt technique) requires the macro definition (probably in some other header), and knowledge of how to use it; however, the compiler errors are very readable (identical to the explicit). Lastly, the explicit technique is most obvious, but may require extra typing by the programmer.